# zoom and pan not working in fabricjs for touch devices

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, fabricjs

I implemented the drawing feature on canvas using fabric js in angular. all things works perfect for me. but Now I have to add canvas zoom and pan options using fabric js. for that I refer this [fabricjs example](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5#pan_zoom).

Zoom and Pan option working on Mouse Event there is no issue. but when I'm using Touch Devices it not works.

see below code what I tried.

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ElementRef,
  VERSION,
  ViewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { fabric } from 'fabric';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  version = VERSION.full;

  @ViewChild('mainHtmlCanvas') mainHtmlCanvas!: ElementRef;

  mainCanvas!: fabric.Canvas;
  isDragging: boolean = false;
  selection: boolean = true;
  lastPosX!: number;
  lastPosY!: number;
  isDrawingMode: boolean = false;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mainCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(this.mainHtmlCanvas.nativeElement, {
      hoverCursor: 'pointer',
      selection: this.selection,
      selectionBorderColor: 'blue',
      width: 800,
      height: 500,
      allowTouchScrolling: true,
      isDrawingMode: this.isDrawingMode,
      backgroundColor: '#eee',
    });

    const rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 100,
      top: 100,
      fill: 'red',
      width: 50,
      height: 100,
    });
    this.mainCanvas.add(rect);
    // this.mainCanvas.centerObject(rect);

    const circle = new fabric.Circle({
      left: 80,
      top: 50,
      fill: 'pink',
      radius: 50,
    });
    this.mainCanvas.add(circle);
    this.mainCanvas.centerObject(circle);

    const sequre = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 300,
      top: 350,
      fill: 'blue',
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    });
    this.mainCanvas.add(sequre);

    const textbox = new fabric.Textbox('ABC Text', {
      left: 300,
      top: 100,
      width: 150,
      fontSize: 25,
      textAlign: 'center',
    });
    this.mainCanvas.add(textbox);

    this.mainCanvas.on('touch:gesture', (e) => {
      console.log('touch:gesture', e);
    });

    this.mainCanvas.on('touch:drag', (e) => {
      console.log('touch:drag', e);
    });

    this.mainCanvas.on('mouse:wheel', (opt) => {
      var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
      var zoom = this.mainCanvas.getZoom();
      zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
      if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
      if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
      this.mainCanvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom);
      opt.e.preventDefault();
      opt.e.stopPropagation();
      var vpt = this.mainCanvas.viewportTransform ?? [];
      if (zoom < 400 / 1000) {
        vpt[4] = 200 - (1000 * zoom) / 2;
        vpt[5] = 200 - (1000 * zoom) / 2;
      } else {
        if (vpt[4] >= 0) {
          vpt[4] = 0;
        } else if (vpt[4] < this.mainCanvas.getWidth() - 1000 * zoom) {
          vpt[4] = this.mainCanvas.getWidth() - 1000 * zoom;
        }
        if (vpt[5] >= 0) {
          vpt[5] = 0;
        } else if (vpt[5] < this.mainCanvas.getHeight() - 1000 * zoom) {
          vpt[5] = this.mainCanvas.getHeight() - 1000 * zoom;
        }
      }
    });

    this.mainCanvas.on('mouse:down', (opt) => {
      var evt = opt.e;
      if (evt.altKey === true) {
        this.isDragging = true;
        this.selection = false;
        this.lastPosX = evt.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = evt.clientY;
      }
    });
    this.mainCanvas.on('mouse:move', (opt) => {
      if (this.isDragging) {
        var e = opt.e;
        var vpt = this.mainCanvas.viewportTransform ?? [];
        vpt[4] += e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
        vpt[5] += e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
        this.mainCanvas.requestRenderAll();
        this.lastPosX = e.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = e.clientY;
      }
    });
    this.mainCanvas.on('mouse:up', (opt) => {
      // on mouse up we want to recalculate new interaction
      // for all objects, so we call setViewportTransform
      this.mainCanvas.setViewportTransform(
        this.mainCanvas.viewportTransform ?? []
      );
      this.isDragging = false;
      this.selection = true;
    });
  }
}
```

```
<p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
<p>
  angular <b>v{{ version }}</b>
</p>

<div style="border: 1px solid">
  <canvas #mainHtmlCanvas></canvas>
</div>
```

> "fabric": "5.3.0",
> "@types/fabric": "^5.3.4",
> "typescript": "4.8.2",
> "angular": "14.2.0"

## You can test my Code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-version-ojwqk5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Thank you

Comment: I found this issue https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/8849